# Calculation of the Collapse of Star into Black Hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, stars, supernova

Using equations or a method of calculation using general relativity, how could one calculate the collapse of a star into  a black hole?

Comment: Snyder-Oppenhimier Collapse

Comment: There's a recent [AstroBite about the Oppenheimer & Snyder gravitational collapse paper](https://astrobites.org/2021/04/09/from-dust-bunnies-to-black-holes-oppenheimer-snyder-collapse/).